# Technologies required for connectedTv

Tags: java, php, algorithm, web-applications

Can anyone help me suggesting which technologies will be useful to implement a ConnectedTv.

In ConnectedTv where the Internet is configured in TV, while watching TV, users can browse the TV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web browser with a good 5-point navigation implementation, support for web standards, support for [CE-HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CE-HTML) and a TCP/IP stack.

Comment: Up, Down, Left, Right, Select. The buttons on a remote control.

Comment: @David, I found Yahoo is coming up with this, do you know any Other company which offers the similar kind of services

Comment: Yahoo! is? I thought they just did Yahoo! Widgets for TV, which never caught on. (Not least because every TV manufacturer twiddled different options and ran their own App Store, so you had to write a different version for each type of TV). Samsung have dropped Yahoo! Widgets for their 2010 TVs (as far as I can tell) in favour of a real web browser. (Much as I love watching TV on my Samsung, the Yahoo! Widgets system is hateful — limited software and very slow, but that is probably down far more to politics and the hardware than it is the software)

Comment: Companies making TVs (or devices that plug into TVs such as Blu-Ray players) with browsers (or software to install on those devices) include Sony, Samsung, Phillips, Opera, Cello, IP Vision, and dozens of others.

Comment: @David, Have build any similar widgets?